# Postman Is Unable To Verify Valid Certificate

Tags: postman, ssl-certificate

I have an API hosted on IIS on a remote server that has a valid certificate. When I load the endpoint on my browser (edge), it shows that it is secure which implies the certificate is valid:

[image: edge picture]

However, when I try to post to the endpoint on Postman, I get the below error:

[image: postman error]

It seems most solutions online suggest avoiding the problem by turning off SSL verification, but I want the certificate to be verified and for the request to pass ok.

I also wrote some C# code to test the endpoint and I had no issues with certificate verification which leads me to believe the issue is with my Postman settings.